# SSD Analogue for non-SSD

Tags: single-word-requests

Sorry for the pun, but I couldn't resist.  Is there an easy to speak and explain acronym or word for non-solid state drives?  Or what, if any, is the antonym of solid-state?

Addendum:
After reading the wikipedia article on HDDs linked to by @FumbleFingers I think that it is the proper mechanical analogue for SSD.  The essence of my question now is there a single word antonym for solid-state?

Comment: Sorry I misread your usage. Comment deleted. You've got me really lost with vacuum tubes though - were they ever used for *data storage*? I can remember paper tape and punched cards holding data, and I know valves with vacuum tubes were used long before silicon transistors, for *processing*. But did they ever meaningfully hold *data*? The generic term for all of them today is just *mass-storage device*.

Comment: Perfectly understandable, I too have deleted my overly snarky comment.  As far as I know valves were never used for data storage per se, however in my experience solid-state originated as a term that is in opposition to vacuum tube technology.  A transistor is the solid-state replacement of the vacuum tube.  So, I guess what I'm asking is there a term in the vernacular of electronics that is an antonym for solid-state.

Answer (score 6):

The ones with moving parts are [mechanical drives](http://www.davebritzius.com/solid-state-drives-vs-mechanical-drives-the-real-world-difference), or more commonly [HDDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive) *(hard disk drives)*.

I note from OP's comment that he thinks SSDs are a subtype of HDD. I don't agree with that - but then again I'm not all that keen on *Solid-State **Drive*** in the first place. So far as I'm concerned, they aren't "drives" at all - they're just high-capacity memory chips with traditional disc drive data interface protocols.

Comment: Interestingly [Seagate](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/internal-hard-drives/) list "Solid State Drives" under "Internal Hard Drives", alongside "Laptop Hard Drives" and "Desktop Hard Drives", and don't seem to use "disk" at all.

Comment: Oh, and I'd ditch the apostrophes in SSD's and HDD's.

Comment: I had a boss once who had previously worked for a disc manufacturer, and he habitually referred to any bit of equipment that we might be working on as a _drive_.

Comment: If you want to be derogatory compared to modern SSD, the term "spinning rust" is common (the magnetic material is an iron oxide)

Comment: Mechanical drive is common if you want to emphasise the moving nature - ie. "SSDs can tolerate higher level of vibration than mechanical drives"

Answer (score 4):

I use HDD (Hard Disk Drive) when referring to non solid state drives.

Comment: That's not bad, but I view the term HDD more as referring to the whole category of internal storage devices for PCs, rather than a specific technology.

Comment: @d34dh0r53 - Well, since it stands for "Hard Disk Drive", which is in fact a particular technology, I'd say your view of the term in that case may be slightly in error.

Answer (score 1):

HDD is the commonly-accepted label for non-SSD drives.

Speaking as a techie, the only true one-word antonym I've come across for SSD is "platters", referring to the spinning platters in HDDs

Other terms I've come across:

- Mechanical Hard Drive
- Spinning Drive
- Traditional Storage

Answer (score 1):

I would say *[magnetic disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_disk)* is a fair analog of *solid-state* with regard to drives.

Answer (score 0):

Common usage among SysAdmins is that HDD refers to drives with spinning platters and *not* to SSDs.  [This search on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=ssd%20hdd) is neither exhaustive nor conclusive, but you can see in the questions and snippets of answers that SSD is not treated as a specific type of HDD.

WRT your addendum, I don't think it makes sense to speak of an "opposite" to solid state drives.  Currently, there are only a few types of "storage drives:"

1. hard drives (with spinning platters)
2. optical drives
3. thumb drives (basically memory sticks and memory cards)
4. RAM drives (computer memory accessed as if it were a hard drive)
5. solid state drives, similar in concept to thumb drives, i.e. flash memory packaged to appear to the computer as if it were a spinning hard drive

3, 4, and 5 are all "solid state" in the sense of using chips as the storage medium, but they're very different technologies, and then 1 and 2 are very different from those and quite different from each other.